# Not able to reach any domain on Port 80,443 but can do ssh. This is an AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, tcp, iptables, network-traffic

I am not able to reach any domain via CURL from the AWS instance. I have checked all the configuration everything seems ok to me. Attaching output of few commands.

**iptables**

```
root@ip-172-31-26-121:~# iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4177 packets, 404K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3751 packets, 930K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
root@ip-172-31-26-121:~#
```

**UFW not installed**

**netstat**

```
root@ip-172-31-26-121:~# !netstat
netstat -ntup -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      870/nginx: master p
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      884/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      870/nginx: master p
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      641/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      844/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      870/nginx: master p
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      844/sshd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           641/systemd-resolve
udp        0      0 172.31.26.121:68        0.0.0.0:*                           618/systemd-network
```

**curl**

```
root@ip-172-31-26-121:~# curl -v facebook.com
* Rebuilt URL to: facebook.com/
*   Trying 185.60.216.35...
* TCP_NODELAY set



^C
root@ip-172-31-26-121:~#
```

One more thing which I noticed is everything works after instance reboot for 30-40 sec, then again it stops working

Can anyone please suggest what else can i check?

Comment: did you check outbound rule for your instance? or is the instance in public subnet?

Comment: All traffic is open in outbound rule

Comment: is there internet gateway attached with instance?

Comment: Yes it is attached